# How to boot an existing OS/disk from a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtual-machine, multi-boot, vmware-player

I have a dual boot with Windows 7/Linux and I want to be able to boot the Windows 7 from a virtual machine (VMware Player) without converting the real machine to a virtual machine.

How to boot an existing Windows 7 disk from the Linux VMPlayer virtual machine?

Comment: Do you want to run Windows 7 on the physical machine as well as on the VM?

Comment: @yassarikhan786 yes, practically I'd like to boot the real disk in the virtual machine but be able to boot it also in the dual boot if I need to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible by choosing "Use a physical disk" while setting up the VM, however this is

a) bound to be problematic in case the Win7 partition is on the same disk - you'll need a bootloader, and it's normally not possible to choose "Use entire disk" when the disk itself is in use by the system,

b) (more important) **Windows may or may not like the hardware changing** while booting on different machines (from the windows POV). You may end up with everything from working to 10min+ boot times to an entirely unbootable system! Also, note that the Windows Genuine Advantage may or may not think that the system is pirated after dual-host booting.

Especially for reason b), **do a backup before**! As for a software, I recommend Acronis True Image, it's cheap.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a way to boot from an existing hard-disk in VM Player, just follow these steps:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]